# DistinguishedName attribute missing from OU properties>attribute editor

Tags: active-directory

As the title says, I used to be able to go into Active Directory (ADUC) and right-click any OU, go to properties, then attribute editor and find the DistinguishedName attribute for the DN - but DistinguishedName is no longer in the list of attributes (I have advanced features enabled).

I know how to find the DN in PowerShell so it's not a problem (and they definitely have a DN...), I'm just confused as to why it's randomly missing from attribute editor when it used to always be there. I'm not sure if our sysadmin had messed with our AD schema recently or not, but I can't imagine that would randomly cause certain attributes to disappear from attribute editor in ADUC.

Any ideas or questions I should ask the sysadmin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way this could happen is if "Show only writable attributes" is selected in the "Filter" menu, since `distinguishedName` is not writable.

[image]

Comment: Holy crap, you're right - I didn't even know that filter existed...now I get to figure out how that even got enabled :D.  Thanks